# how to show input value from one input into another

Tags: jquery

I have this code here http://jsfiddle.net/RzBeM/65/ you will see two input fields called quantity. Basically the first part multiplies the quantity by the Card Points value and returns a value and in the second part the quantity multiplies by the Card Value and gives a value. The problem is i have to enter in the number into both inputs i would like to have one input but do both multiplications at once. Also if you type in a value and erase it it displays NaN how do i prevent that?

Comment: NaN means Not a Number. Let me take a look at the code. Two seconds. Could you try to write your post again? I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do. You'd like to remove the first calculation from being shown?

Comment: @OptimusCrime oh ok thank you is there a way to only accept integers and nothing else?

Comment: Your variabel `howMany` point to Card points, is that intended?

Comment: @bammab: Could you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you have a modified version of your code. i removed the second quantity input

```
$("input[id*=-id-]").keyup(function() {
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    var cardPoints = parseInt($(this).parents("tr").find('input:eq(1)').val());
    var realValue = parseInt($(this).parents("tr").find('input:eq(2)').val());

    cardCalc = cardPoints * quantity;
    realCalc = realValue * quantity;

    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(2)").html(cardCalc);
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(4)").html(realCalc);
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/RzBeM/82/

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue with your code is that you have all the HTML elements with the same ID, which is incorrect. I have updated it and you can get the latest here: http://jsfiddle.net/RzBeM/92/

The code becomes something like:

```
$("#amazon5-id-sb5").keyup(function() {
    //card
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    var howMany = parseInt($("#amazon5-id-sb6").val());
    var subTotal = quantity * howMany;
    //real value
    var realValue = parseInt($("#amazon5-id-sb8").val());
    var realTotal = quantity * realValue;

    //assign subTotal to the td0
    $("#amazon5-id-sb7").html(subTotal);
    $("#amazon5-id-sb9").html(realTotal);
});
```